# Выбор алгоритма выборки объектов из очереди

Tags: многопоточность, java

Привет всем!

Есть такой вопросик, ребята. Есть три потока и очередь. Один поток добавляет объекты в очередь, второй и третий, соответственно, забирают.

Вопрос в том, как лучше реализовать выборку объектов из очереди. Есть 2 варианта, какой из них предпочтительней с точки зрения многопоточности?

Первый:

```
// Класс, который реализует синхронизированную очередь
public synchronized void add(Object o) {
    someQueue.add(o);
}

public synchronized Object get() {
    if(someQueue.size() == 0)
        return null;
    else
        return someQueue.remove(0);
}

// Класс, вынимающий объекты. Запущено два инстанса
public void run() {
    while(True) {
        Object o = queue.get()
        if (o == null) {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            continue;
        }
        ......
}
```

Второй:

```
// Класс, который реализует синхронизированную очередь
public synchronized void add(Object o) {
    someQueue.add(o);
    notifyAll();
}

public synchronized Object get() {
    if(someQueue.size() == 0)
        return null;
    else
        return someQueue.remove(0);
}

// Класс, вынимающий объекты. Запущено два инстанса
public void run() {
    while(True) {
        Object o = queue.get()
        if (o == null) {
            try {
                synchronized(queue) {
                    queue.wait(1000);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            continue;
        }
        ......
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так, да. Вы сами ответили. Используйте либо [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) либо [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html). Conditional Variable тут совсем ни к чему. А ещё можно использовать [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

```
private final LinkedBlockingQueue<String> myStrangeQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();

public void add(String message) {
    myStrangeQueue.put(message);
}

public void run() {
    try {
        while (true)
            processMessage(myStrangeQueue.take());
    } catch(InterrupedException ignore) {
    }
}

private void processMessage(String message) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Третий. С использованием [Condition Variable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html).

Comment: Вы про ArrayBlockingQueue?

Comment: Я про await() + signal() вместо sleep(1)

Comment: Извините за назойливость, нельзя ли привести пример, переделав мой код? А то что-то, думается, вы предлагате тот же вариант 2, только вид сбоку.

Comment: Так и есть. wait + signal - это то же самое, что synchronized в данном случае.